# PHP & SQL, querying for nested year, month, and number of posts for a custom blog

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to display an archived list of the year, month with number of blog posts in a link. Something like this:

- 2013

  - December (3)
- 2014

  - January (4)
  - February (2)

...etc and it will link to a page where it will display all the posts in that month.

I tried:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as year, MONTH(date) as month, ....
```

and did in php:

```
<ul>
  <li><?php echo $year; ?>
      <ul>
         <li><?php echo $month; ?> (<?php echo $countpost; ?>)</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I'm just getting a blank page, I'm pretty sure I did the query wrong.

EDIT: adding database

```
postid | title | date | content | userid | active
```

Comment: @user1613360 added db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these queries to get a output like what you have described.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");

$result=mysqli_query($con,"select distinct YEAR(date) as myyear from table");

while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

echo "<b>".$fetch['myyear']."</b><br />";

$q1="select MONTH(date) as postmonth,count(*) as postcount from table where year(date)=".$fetch['myyear']." group by MONTH(date)";
$temp1=mysqli_query($con,$q1);
while($temp=mysqli_fetch_array($temp1))

echo "<b>".$temp['postmonth']."</b> (".$temp['postcount'].")<br />";

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as year, MONTH(date) as month, COUNT(postid) as countpost
FROM postTable
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date);
```

See more in demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeb91/1)

Comment: not really working, it's only giving me one result. Only one month is showing.

Comment: it also doesn't work if I put `GROUP BY YEAR(date) as year, MONTH(date) as month`

Comment: Check our the demo, and YES, we can not use AS keyword in GROUP BY clause. Forgot to remove it.